# Powershell Script for Okta API to add single group to Multiple Apps

Tags: powershell, okta, okta-api

I have a group called Group1 and I have approx 50-60 similar apps that contain the same name like "ABC-423", "ABC-4242" etc.

What i want is to add this single group(Group-1) to this different apps "ABC*" by using Okta API with Powershell (API - https://github.com/gabrielsroka/OktaAPI.psm1)

here is the code I wrote so far

```
#Purpose of Code : We want to Add Group named GRPS1 to Okta Apps that's name contains ABC
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
# [1] Connect to Okta. Do this before making any other calls. - done
Connect-Okta "<redacted>" "https://yourorg.oktapreview.com"
$url = "https://yourorg.oktapreview.com" 
$appdata = @()
$groupid = "00gtx2yruqKg9diIJ0h7" #00gtx2yruqKg9diIJ0h7 => GRPS1
$group = 0
$i=0
$j=0
#Function to Get all Active OKTA Application List
function Get-AllActiveApps($url)
{ 
   # [2] Now we want to Store JSON data from $appdata to Powershell Object - done
   $appdata = @(Invoke-Method GET "/api/v1/apps?status eq 'Active'")   
   foreach($i in $appdata[0].label)
   {
      # [3.1] Use a For loop to get one by one application object checked with name contaning ABC
      if ($i -like '*ABC*') 
      {
         # [3.2] Assign Group to all apps that's name contains ABC
         $appnumber = $appdata[0][$j].id
         Add-OktaAppGroup($appnumber,$groupid,$group)
      }
      else 
      {
    
      }
      $j++
   }
}
Get-AllActiveApps($url)
```

The problem is at function Add-OktaAppGroup($appnumber,$groupid,$group) because the loop it is passing all application-ids as one single array and the function can only process one group id at a time

Can anyone help how to solve this?

Comment: Please include the result of `Invoke-Method GET "/api/v1/apps?status eq 'Active'"` in your question. It's hard to tell what you need to do when the data structure you work with is unclear.

Comment: It should be `Add-OktaAppGroup $appnumber $groupid $group`, not `Add-OktaAppGroup($appnumber,$groupid,$group)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Get-AllActiveApps` function is pretty much useless. After taking out all the parts that don't have anything to do with the task of getting all active apps, we would be left with

```
function Get-AllActiveApps
{ 
    Invoke-Method GET '/api/v1/apps?filter=status eq "Active"'
}
```

and that function already exists in `OktaAPI.psm1`, in a better form:

```
function Get-OktaApps($filter, $limit = 20, $expand, $url = "/api/v1/apps?filter=$filter&limit=$limit&expand=$expand&q=$q", $q)
{
     # ...
}
```

So let's use this instead, with the `-filter` parameter.

The rest of your task (filtering some more, and doing something for each item) is PowerShell 101. You don't need any custom functions or loops for that, a pipeline is enough:

```
Connect-Okta -baseUrl "https://yourorg.oktapreview.com" -token "<redacted>"

# using a hash for group IDs allows easy reference in the rest of the code
$groups = @{
    GRPS1 = "00gtx2yruqKg9diIJ0h7"
}

$activeApps = Get-OktaApps -filter 'status eq "ACTIVE"' -limit 200

$activeApps.objects | Where-Object label -like '*ABC*' | Where-Object {
    $appGroups = Get-OktaAppGroups -appid $_.id -limit 200
    $appGroups.objects.id -notcontains $groups.GRPS1
} | ForEach-Object {
    Add-OktaAppGroup -appid $_.id -groupid $groups.GRPS1
}
```

Notes

- You don't need to set the `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol`, `Connect-Okta` already does that.
- App groups are not part of [the API response](https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/apps/#application-object) when you get a list of apps, that's why the second `Where-Object` fetches the app groups for each app.
- `$appGroups.objects.id` will be  an array of the IDs of all returned [groups](https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/groups/#group-object). `-notcontains $groups.GRPS1` produces `$true` or `$false`, depending. This will be the filter criterion for `Where-Object`, i.e. *"all apps where the list of group IDs does not contain that particular ID"*.
- Many Okta API responses are [paged](https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/core-okta-api/#pagination). 200 objects per page seems to be the upper limit, as per the API documentation. Pay attention to situations where there are more objects than that. Read the documentation to `OktaAPI.psm1` to learn how to handle these cases, because the code above does not.
- You should probably add some debugging output. Read about [`Write-Debug`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-debug) and the `$DebugPreference` global variable.

Comment: Hi @Tomalak, Thanks a lot for your detailed response. Let me check this one and get back to you. I am bit new to programming so please pardon my silly mistakes

Comment: @Pratik The code in this answer is untested - I don't have an Okta account and I've never used their API. I pieced it together from the API documentation and the PowerShell module source code. You will probably need to iron out some details.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the Okta Apps API can let you search by name using the `-q` parameter, eg

```
Get-OktaApps -q "ABC-"
```

It will return up to 200 apps; you can paginate for more.

See https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/apps/#list-applications